# Segmentation Fault on graph simplify

Tags: python, python-2.7, igraph

I am merging nodes in a graph using `contract_vertices` and then calling `simplify` on the graph but I am getting segmentation fault in doing so. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is the code to reproduce the error:

```
from igraph import summary, read, Graph
g = Graph()
g.add_vertices(5)
g.vs["name"] = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
g.add_edge("1","2")
merge_vertex_list = [1,1,3,3,3]
g.contract_vertices(merge_vertex_list,"first")
g.simplify()
```

The error I am getting:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Note: when I am calling `contract_vertices` without second argument i.e. `combine_attrs` parameter it is working fine.

Comment: It looks like `igraph` relies on C or C++ libraries. Did you compile yourself or install a binary? Either way the likely culprit is a shared library on your system that doesn't work correctly with `igraph`.  You may need to upgrade the supporting libraries.

Comment: I installed C core using Homebrew: `homebrew install homebrew/science/igraph` and then `pip install python-igraph`. I updated the packages but still the same. I am installing python-igraph in virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason for it. The list I am passing for merging the array should contain contiguous integers, which will form new indexes of vertices. In above case I was passing `[1,1,3,3,3]` which when changed to `[0,0,1,1,1]` worked fine. Still I think it should have shown a meaningful error message.